# Inner join three tables with vertical and horizontal references

Tags: mysql, join

I hope the title describes my problem correctly, forgive me if I'm wrong.

I would like to retrieve the distance between two locations (CN and US in this example) based on the following three tables:

**Shipments**

```
    |----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
    |         from         |        to         |    distance    |
    |----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
    |          CN          |        US         |                |
    |----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
```

**Locations**

```
    |----------------------|-------------------|
    |       location       |   location_id     |
    |----------------------|-------------------|
    |          CN          |        123        |
    |          US          |        456        |
    |----------------------|-------------------|
```

**Distances**

```
    |----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
    |   from_location_id   |   to_location_id  |    distance    |
    |----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
    |         123          |       456         |      789       |
    |----------------------|-------------------|----------------|
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
    UPDATE Shipments SHP
    INNER JOIN Locations LOC1 ON SHP.from = LOC1.location
    INNER JOIN Distances DST1 ON LOC1.location_id = DST1.from_location_id

    INNER JOIN Locations LOC2 ON SHP.to =  LOC2.location
    INNER JOIN Distances DST2 ON LOC2.location_id = DST2.to_location_id
    SET SHP.distance = DST2.distance;
```

I'm having trouble setting the correct alias to make the vertical inner join happen. Also I'm not sure how to use the alias in the SET clause at the end. I've tried using DST2, but this delivers false results.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use below update code, self-join twice on `Locations` then update.

```
UPDATE Shipments SHP 
INNER JOIN Locations LOC1 ON SHP.`from` = LOC1.location 
INNER JOIN Distances DST1 ON LOC1.location_id = DST1.from_location_id
INNER JOIN Locations LOC2 ON LOC2.location_id = DST1.to_location_id AND SHP.`to` = LOC2.location
SET SHP.distance = DST1.distance
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Shipments
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad014c/1/0)**:

```
| from | to | distance |
|------|----|----------|
|   CN | US |      789 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS locations;

CREATE TABLE locations
(location_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,location CHAR(2) UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO locations VALUES
(123,'CN'),
(456,'US');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS distances;

CREATE TABLE distances
(from_location_id INT NOT NULL
,to_location_id INT NOT NULL
,distance INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(from_location_id,to_location_id)
);

INSERT INTO distances VALUES
(123,456,789);

SELECT a.location `from`
     , b.location `to`
     , x.distance 
  FROM distances x 
  JOIN locations a  
    ON a.location_id = x.from_location_id 
  JOIN locations b  
    ON b.location_id = x.to_location_id;
+------+------+----------+
| from | to   | distance |
+------+------+----------+
| CN   | US   |      789 |
+------+------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```